# Ruby on Rails assets:precompile ownership

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline

I have a Ruby on Rails based site, in which I need to run `rake assets:precompile` to get the correct pre-compiled assets. Whenever I run this command, however, everything in the `tmp` directory of my application goes back to being owned by root (which is a Very Bad Thing™ as my application requires ownership by the `www-data` user).

How can I get Rails to quit changing the permissions?

Comment: do you absolutely have to run it as root?

Comment: Run what as root? Everything is run as www-data (hence rails cries at me when it can't do things in tmp because it's running as www-data), I'm confused as to why rails is creating the tmp files with an owner of root.

Comment: so you're running the rake task as `www-data` ? (e.g. with `sudo -u www-data`)

Comment: Ah I see, no - I'm running the rake task as sudo. Would running the rake task as www-data fix all my problems? (because I can do that, I just assumed that running with root permissions was a good idea)

Comment: it should at least preserve the proper owner and group of your files. but you may run into other problems, e.g. if you're using `rvm`. just try it.

Comment: Had to chown manifest.yml to www-data, but after that it's all working fine if I run the command while su'd in as www-data :D (Submit as answer please so I can mark it correct). Note that using your 'sudo -u www-data' on the other hand didn't actually work: 'Permission denied - /root'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `rake assets:precompile` as `root`, all files generated by this task will belong to `root`. you should run it as `www-data` (e.g. with sudo -u www-data), as well as any other task / ruby script / rails console on your production server, to prevent messing up the file permissions. to get things right for now, you should `chown -R` your application dir, before continuing